# Web page loading issues

Tags: unity

I am currently working in Ubuntu 14.04 & trying to access a web page using Firefox & Chrome both but its not loading the web page. I am getting the error like 
The connection has timed out

The server at omappedia.org is taking too long to respond.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

try again..
I am facing this problem for last 2 weeks. Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: The site opens for me in firefox - have you checked your computer and your routers to see if the site is being blocked somewhere?

Comment: how do i check it?

Comment: Blocked websites in firefox are either enabled by parental controls, or some add-ons.  In Ubuntu, websites can be blocked in the /etc/hosts file by redirecting them to the local computer.  Most routers have specific options for blocking websites that vary by router, and some ISP's also provide services to block websites.

Comment: How do I disable it?

Comment: If it's not in your firefox, or in Ubuntu, you will need to learn how to talk to your router, and/or your ISP

Comment: I have disabled two of the security options in Firefox 1.Block reported attack sites & 2.Block reported web forgeries but still facing the same issue. If it is in Ubuntu then how do I disable it?

Comment: I am very sure that it's not the problem with ISP because the same page is opening in Windows but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post the output of `wget -S http://omappedia.org` from the terminal?

Comment: actually text is limited here so i'll post one after another  $ wget -S http://omappedia.org 
--2014-07-19 17:48:31--  http://omappedia.org/
Resolving omappedia.org (omappedia.org)... 184.73.187.199
Connecting to omappedia.org (omappedia.org)|184.73.187.199|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Date: Sat, 19 Jul 2014 12:18:32 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.26 with Suhosin-Patch mod_perl/2.0.3 Perl/v5.8.8
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.26
  Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
  Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Jul 2014 12:18:32 GMT
  Location: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
  Content-Length: 0
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page [following]
--2014-07-19 17:48:32--  http://omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Reusing existing connection to omappedia.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

Comment: --2014-07-19 18:03:33--  (try: 2)  http://omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Connecting to omappedia.org (omappedia.org)|184.73.187.199|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

--2014-07-19 18:18:36--  (try: 3)  http://omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Connecting to omappedia.org (omappedia.org)|184.73.187.199|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

Comment: above output is taken after waiting around 20 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'dig'

dig  omappedia.org

For me it returns: 
(unnecessary lines omitted)

**omappedia.org.        7200    IN  A   184.73.187.199**

It does not respond to a ping,

If I go directly to the IP address (184.73.187.199) I end up at "university.pandaboard.org" indicating that it is either a loadbalancer, or a server running multiple sites.

You should not be able to access http://university.pandaboard.org/ either if the connection is terminated by your ISP on IP-level.

If you run 'dig' and get another IP address that may indicate that the DNS server you are using are either messed up or may intentionally give you a wrong answer.

Try changing to Googles DNS servers, 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 and see if you get another answer.

Comment: How do I use dig? Please elaborate. If I type dig omappedia.org in address bar then it shows me various google results & when I type digomappedia.org then it shows me the error server not found.

Comment: Dig is small tool that you will find in the 'dnsutils' package.
You use it to query a DNS server for the ip of an dns address. It returns and answer with the public information for that address, including with IP or IP's that is associated with the address.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your comment to the full. Dig is a terminal/console program. Start gnome-terminal (for example) and type 'dig omappedia.org'

If it says 'command not found' you will need to install the packages 'dnsutils' by running

sudo apt-get install dnsutils

Comment: I tried in terminal it didn't say command not found. i.e. dnsutils is present in my Ubuntu. So now how do I proceed further.

Comment: What did it say?

Comment: ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> omappedia.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13639
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;omappedia.org.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
omappedia.org.  3918 IN A 184.73.187.199

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
omappedia.org.  3918 IN NS ns2.zoneedit.com.
omappedia.org.  3918 IN NS ns15.zoneedit.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: 
ns2.zoneedit.com. 162883 IN A 69.72.158.226
some more info but text is limited here.

Comment: The remaining text is : ns15.zoneedit.com. 133512 IN A 67.210.114.13

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 19 00:24:05 IST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: Does not seem to be a dns error.
If you connect another computer to your network, does it behave in the same way?